# Why is my dataSnapshot.val() equal to null?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

**CODE:**

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $firebaseArray, $timeout) {

    $scope.data = [];
    var _start = 0;
    var _end = 4;
    var _n = 5;

    console.log("1");

    $scope.getDataset = function() {
        console.log("4");
        fb.orderByChild('time').startAt(_start).endAt(_end).limitToLast(_n).on("value", function(dataSnapshot) {
            console.log("5");
            $scope.data.push(dataSnapshot.val());
            console.log("THE VALUE:"+dataSnapshot.val());
            console.log("6");
        });

        console.log("7");


        _start = _start + _n;
        _end = _end + _n;

        console.log("8");
    };

    console.log("2");

    $scope.getDataset()

    console.log("3");

});
```

---

**DATABASE:**

```
"posts" {
    "fun" {
         "-Kzugwouzgafsdbkuzbf" {
             "time": 1478443829263
         }
         "-Krugwouzgafawdrawdr" {
             "time": 1478446164691
         }
    }
}
```

---

**QUESTION:**

Why is my `dataSnapshot.val()` equal to `null` ?

**N.B.:**

I want to order the posts by timestamp and query the 5 most recent.

Comment: Please include the minimal, complete information (JSON + code) that is needed to reproduce the problem. So the actual data that you query against and the query with hard-coded values for `_start`, `_end` and `_n`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Done.

Comment: Thanks. Now also please give the minimal actual JSON that is needed. And finally: how do you determine that `snapshot.val()` is `null`? Nothing in the code you shared displays its value.

Comment: Done. As for the JSON, I will update the database text.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Done all now :)

Comment: @Coder1000 -- Is your `console.log("5")` ever being run.. also, why **another** question - you keep updating your bounty and posting new!?

Comment: @tymeJV Yes, all console.log statements get printed if I use ref.on("value") instead of ref.on("child_added").  Another question because this one is really specific to Firebase, so I can't include it in my other question. Regardless, once I get a functioning infinite scroll, I will award the bounty to the person who contributed most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing the timestamps as strings, but passing in numbers.

```
"time": "1456273845127"
var _start = 0;
```

Comparing strings to numbers won't work. If you pass in strings, it does work:

```
fb.orderByChild('time').startAt("0").endAt("4").limitToLast(5).on("value", function(dataSnapshot) {
    console.log("5");
    console.log("THE VALUE:"+dataSnapshot.numChildren()+', '+dataSnapshot.val());
    console.log("6");
});
```

Prints:

> "5"
>
> "THE VALUE:2, [object Object]"
>
> "6"

See http://jsbin.com/tucufor/edit?js,console

For future questions: if you reproduce the problem in a jsbin, like I did for my answer, we'll both have the minimum code+json needed for your question within easy reach.

**Update**

Since you indicated that you're storing the timestamps as numbers, the explanation for the behavior is different. When ordering/filtering on numeric values, Firebase will do a numeric comparison. And the current timestamp is way bigger than the `4` that you use in your code.

```
fb.orderByChild('time').startAt(0).endAt(Date.now()).limitToLast(5).on("value", function(dataSnapshot) {
    console.log("5");
    console.log("THE VALUE:"+dataSnapshot.numChildren()+', '+dataSnapshot.val());
    console.log("6");
});
```

This gives me a list of two items again:

> "5"
>
> "THE VALUE:2, [object Object]"
>
> "6"

Comment: Oops. My bad: the time stamps are actually ints, not Strings :/

Comment: I just realized I misused startAt and endAt. Fixing now.